# Google Apps Script AddOn: onChange trigger programatically with misleading permission scope text

Tags: google-apps-script

By Google documentation, an `onChange` trigger for a Spreadsheet addon has to be created programmatically via `ScriptApp.newTrigger(...)...`.

`newtrigger` requires the scope :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp
```

When the user is asked for granting permissions, the text presented is:

> Allow this application to run when you are not present

I understand this function can create time based trigger, but for a simple `onChange` in a Spreadsheet, I would understand if the user declines it due to that text.

Is there a way to have an `onChange` trigger without this scope for changes (not `onEdit`) in spreadsheets?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*The only way to create a trigger on behalf of a user programmatically is using `ScriptApp.newTrigger()`, and this method requires the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp` scope. No other scope will allow this to run.*

*You can however set up an `onChange()` trigger for the Spreadsheet, which will run regardless of who makes the change to the sheet.*

#### More Information:

When you set up a trigger, you are allowing an app/script/function to run, on behalf of you, without you manually running the function. Asking a user to create a trigger will require them to authorise that ***they consent to the script doing something on their behalf.***

You can however, set up the trigger yourself. As long as the function that will run on the trigger doesn't violate any of the [installable trigger restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) then this will run on the Sheet as long as it has been authorised to run by you.

Remember though, that if you set up the trigger yourself, the script will always execute as you, not as the user. So if the function, for example, sends an email, then the email will be sent on behalf of you - as you were the one that authorised the script.

#### Setting up an Installable Trigger manually:

If setting up the trigger to run as you is an acceptable solution, you can do so by following these steps:

Save the script with the save icon, press the run button (►), and confirm the authentication of running the script.

From here, following the Edit > Current project's triggers menu item, you will have a new page open in the G Suite Developer Hub. Click the + Add Trigger button in the bottom right and set up the trigger settings as follows:

- Choose which function to run: `<your-function-name>`
- Choose which deployment should run: `Head`
- Select event source: `From Spreadsheet`
- Select event type: `On change`

And press save.

This will now run on all changes made to the sheet - regardless of who made the change. Just remember that as far as execution goes, you're the script runner.

#### References:

- [Class ScriptApp | Apps Script - `.newTrigger(functionName)` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newtriggerfunctionname)
- [Installable Triggers | Apps Script - Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)
- [Event Objects | Apps Script - Google Sheets events: Change](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)

Comment: My question was specifically about Editor-AddOns. Add-on installable triggers can't be created manually, see [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers#installable_triggers_in_add-ons)

Comment: In which case my mistake. All the same though, the scope is required and you can't get around that.